# flashing sony xperia sp5303

Tags: 18.04, android, flash, sony, firmware

i am trying to flash a sonyxperia sp5303 using flash tools and
the original firmware by sony (Sony_Xperia_SP_C5303_12.0.A.1.257_Customized_NCB_(by_xperiastockrom.com))

i installed flashtools and run it from the terminal
hit the 'flash' button, connected the device through usb holding the volume down button and here is the log...

[image]

any help?
do i have to 'prepare' the firmware somehow???

thanx network!

Answer (score 0):

An older version of flashtool

**flashtool-0.9.18.6-linux**

did it for me in the end!